# 'Edit' button to open a vf page in new tab

Tags: visualforce, button

I have overriden the standard Edit button with a vf page now I would like open the page in a new tab. How can I do this?

**VF Code:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Notes__c" extensions="Notes" action="{!Redir}">
```

Comment: you can use javascript to open in new tab and redirect from javasript instead of action attribute

Answer (score 2):

Overriding standard buttons with Visualforce pages would not help in opening pages in new tab.

You would have to create new custom button, with

- Display Type: Detail page button
- Behaviour: Execute Javascript

and you could put some code like this:

```
window.open("../apex/yourCustomPage?id={! Account.Id }", "_blank")
```

Modify the page layouts required and replace standard edit button with custom one.